# put variable in quotes from a list loop?

Tags: python, list, variables

I am trying to loop through a list of coins using this code:

```
coin = ["BTC", "NEO", "ETH"]


for item in coin:
    try:
        term = urllib.parse.quote("'" + coin + "-BTC'")
        depth = client.get_order_book(term, limit=50)
    except (KucoinAPIException, KucoinRequestException, KucoinResolutionException) as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

and I receive the error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

What's the most efficient way to accomplish this?  Do I have to split up my list?  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your code won't run as posted, and you failed to provide the full error message.

Comment: Your question says "… from a list loop". Well, that's exactly what you need here and haven't written: a loop over a list.

Comment: I pasted more code, I guess it's not possible?  if so i'll delete it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier (and efficient/Pythonic) to use a `for` loop to achieve this:

```
coin = ["BTC", "NEO", "ETH"]

for i in coin:
    term = urllib.parse.quote("'" + i + "-BTC'")
    depth = client.get_order_book(term, limit=50)
```